# Ocultar divs com ID parecido

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Tenho diversas tags `div` com o id parecido, todas começam com **cn-**, exemplo:

```
<div id="cn-name">...</div>
<div id="cn-email">...</div>
<div id="cn-pass">...</div>
```

Como posso fazer pra interagir com todas elas sem ter que especificar uma por uma? Teria alguma forma de fazer isso pelas inicias dela? Por exemplo:

```
/* no css */
#cn-* {
  display:none;
}

/* no javascript/jquery */
$('#cn-*').hide();
```

Comment: Não poderia haver uma classe para todos esses mesmos campos? Exemplo:  `CNs`, seria mais fácil a manipulação com apenas `$('.CNs').hide()`

Comment: Acho que até daria @MarcelodeAndrade, mas teria que refatorar bastante coisa. De qualquer forma seria uma ótima saída, obrigado.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Veja essas duas opções

CSS:

```
div[id^='cn-'] {
  display:none;
}
```

ou jQuery:

```
$('div[id^="cn-"]').hide();
```

Isso vai te permitir selecionar todos os elementos que contenham `cn-` no começo do ID.

Retirado do SOen: [css-selector-id-contains-part-of-text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155833/css-selector-id-contains-part-of-text)

## Seletores:

- `[atributo^=valor]`: seleciona todos elementos que o `atributo` comece com `valor`
- `[atributo$=valor]`: seleciona todos elementos que o `atributo` termine com `valor`
- `[atributo*=valor]`: seleciona todos elementos que o `atributo` contenha `valor`

Fonte: [seletores CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: Excelente! Era isso mesmo, obrigado @PedroCamaraJunior

Comment: Pedro, o seletor para `#cn-*` (`id`s que iniciam com `cd-`) é `[id^='cn-']`, ao utiliza o `*=` pode retornar elementos que não iniciam com `cn`, porem tem `cn` no nome, como `#bt-cnida`

Comment: @TobyMosque corrigido, valeu pelo toque!