# Seleção parcial de uma classe com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá,

Gostaria de saber se é possível selecionar uma classe/elemento a partir de um valor parcialmente informado, por exemplo:

```
<div class="chart-piso c100 p100 orange big">
   <span id="percPiso">100%</span>
   <div class="slice">
      <div class="bar"></div>
      <div class="fill"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Gostaria de selecionar os elementos apenas informando que as classes contém o `p` antes dos números pois aqueles números são variáveis.

Tentei selecioná-los da seguinte forma e sei que está super errado também haha:

```
$("div[class*='chart-']").removeClass(div[class*='p']);
```

Alguma sugestão?

Obrigado!

Comment: é de fato o tipo de busca que preciso @PedroCamaraJunior, porém não estou conseguindo colocar encaixar ao meu código, segue como tentei fazer: `$("div[class^='chart-']").removeClass("div[class^='p']");`

Comment: Acho que entendi, você precisa selecionar a `div` que contenha a classe `chart-piso` e remover dessa mesma `div ` a classe `p100`. É isso?

Comment: @PedroCamaraJunior que contenha apenas "chart-" pois `piso`é variável e remover sempre a div que contenha um classe iniciada com `p`

Comment: Sim, entendi, foi apenas para usar seu exemplo com exemplo. Mas problema resolvido, retirei meu [voto para fechar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/146039/ocultar-divs-com-id-parecido/146041#146041). :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se entendi o que você está tentando fazer, você poderá usar *regex* para remover a classe que comece com *p* e tenha números depois, algo assim:

```js
$("div[class^='chart-']").removeClass(function(index, className) {
  return (className.match(/(p[0-9]+)/g) || []).join(' ');
});
console.log($("div[class^='chart-']").attr("class"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chart-piso c100 p150 orange big">
  <span id="percPiso">100%</span>
  <div class="slice">
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="fill"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: o console me retornou o seguinte: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ^=`

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente!! Muito obrigado!

Comment: Uma dica seria usar a expressão: `/\bp\d+\b/g` (com *word boundary*)
Caso queira que classes como `.p100s` não sejam removidas.

Answer (score 3):

A resposta do @Lucas Costa já resolve de uma ótima maneira seu problema, vou apenas postar uma outra maneira possível utilizando o `String.replace()`.

```js
var $divChart = $("div[class^='chart-']");
var divClasses = $divChart.prop('class');

$divChart.prop('class', divClasses.replace(/\p[0-9]{3}/g, ''));

console.log('Classes da div: ' + $divChart.prop('class'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chart-piso c100 p100 orange big">
   <span id="percPiso">100%</span>
   <div class="slice">
      <div class="bar"></div>
      <div class="fill"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Uma alternativa à resposta do @pedro-camara-junior com JS puro, certo que foi solicitado com jQuery, mas as vezes não chega a ser necessário, seria o uso do `querySelector()`:

```js
var el = document.querySelector('div[class^=chart-]');
el.className = el.className.replace(/\b(^|\s)p\d+\b/g, '');

console.log("res: " + el.className);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chart-piso c100 p100 orange big">
   <span id="percPiso">100%</span>
   <div class="slice">
      <div class="bar"></div>
      <div class="fill"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```